# Cleansing data with Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, data-cleaning

Consider the following two rows of CSV data:

```
01-15-2014 12:04:05, row1
2014/02/20, row2
```

Row 1 has the desired timestamp format MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS. Row 2 timestamp needs to be transformed to match. SO how can I achieve this task.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the data loaded to say relation A,then pass the column with the date into ToDate function with the desired format.Note that the date should be loaded into a chararray field in relation A.

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE ToDate(A.$0,'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss');
```

Comment: @iamdeep Post your script.

Comment: In-fact code runs without error, but when I dump the relation nothing is displayed as  result.